# SQL Server 2008 Service Broker tutorial -- cannot receive the message (exception in transmission_status)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

I am learning how to use the Service Broker of SQL Server 2008 R2. When following the tutorial [Completing a Conversation in a Single Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839495%28v=sql.105%29). Following the [Lesson 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839488%28v=sql.105%29), I have successfully created the message types, contract, the queues and services. Following the [Lesson 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839499%28v=sql.105%29), I have probably sent the message. However, when trying to receive the message, I get the NULL for the `ReceivedRequestMsg` instead of the sent content.

When looking at the `sys.transmission_queue`, the `transmission_status` for the message says:

> An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue. Error: 15517, State: 1. Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

I have installed SQL Server using the Windows login like `Mycomp\Petr`.  I am using that login also for the lessons.

Can you guess what is the problem? What should I check and or set to make it working?

**Edited 2012/07/16:** For helping to reproduce the problem, here is what I did. Can you reproduce the error if you follow the next steps?

Firstly, I am using Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, Developer Edition, 64-bit (ver. 10.50.2500.0, Root Directory located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL_PRIKRYL05\MSSQL).

1. Following the tutorial advice, I have downloaded the AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf sample database, and copied it into C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL_PRIKRYL05\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf
2. The SQL Server Management Studio had to be launched "As Administrator" to be able to attach the data later. Then I connected the SQL Server.
3. Right click on Databases, context menu Attach..., button Add..., pointed to AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf + OK. Then selected the AdventureWorks2008R2_Log.ldf from the grid below (reported as Not found) and pressed the Remove... button. After pressing OK, the database was attached and the AdventureWorks2008R2_log.LDF was created automatically.
4. The following queries were used for looking at "Service Broker enabled/disabled", and for enabling (the Service Broker was enabled successfully for the database):

---

```
USE master;
GO

SELECT name, is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases;
GO

ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2
      SET ENABLE_BROKER
      WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

SELECT name, is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases;
GO
```

- Then, following the tutorial, the queries below were executed to create the message types, the contract, the queues, and the services:

---

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO

CREATE MESSAGE TYPE
       [//AWDB/1DBSample/RequestMessage]
       VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML;
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE
       [//AWDB/1DBSample/ReplyMessage]
       VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML;
GO

CREATE CONTRACT [//AWDB/1DBSample/SampleContract]
      ([//AWDB/1DBSample/RequestMessage]
       SENT BY INITIATOR,
       [//AWDB/1DBSample/ReplyMessage]
       SENT BY TARGET
      );
GO

CREATE QUEUE TargetQueue1DB;

CREATE SERVICE
       [//AWDB/1DBSample/TargetService]
       ON QUEUE TargetQueue1DB
       ([//AWDB/1DBSample/SampleContract]);
GO

CREATE QUEUE InitiatorQueue1DB;

CREATE SERVICE
       [//AWDB/1DBSample/InitiatorService]
       ON QUEUE InitiatorQueue1DB;
GO
```

So far, so good.

- Then the following queries are used to look at the queues (now empty when used):

---

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO

SELECT * FROM InitiatorQueue1DB WITH (NOLOCK);
SELECT * FROM TargetQueue1DB WITH (NOLOCK);
SELECT * FROM sys.transmission_queue;
GO
```

- The problem manifests when the message is sent:

---

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN DIALOG @InitDlgHandle
     FROM SERVICE
      [//AWDB/1DBSample/InitiatorService]
     TO SERVICE
      N'//AWDB/1DBSample/TargetService'
     ON CONTRACT
      [//AWDB/1DBSample/SampleContract]
     WITH
         ENCRYPTION = OFF;

SELECT @RequestMsg =
       N'<RequestMsg>Message for Target service.</RequestMsg>';

SEND ON CONVERSATION @InitDlgHandle
     MESSAGE TYPE 
     [//AWDB/1DBSample/RequestMessage]
     (@RequestMsg);

SELECT @RequestMsg AS SentRequestMsg;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

When looking at the queues, the `Initiator...` and the `Target...` queues are empty, and the sent message can be found in `sys.transmission_queue` with the above mentioned error reported via the `transmission_status`.

Comment: Thanks for making corrections ;)

Comment: Did you check **[here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/21/sql-server-intorduction-to-service-broker-and-sample-script/)** ?  I am  using sa user to execute the **[sample script](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/21/sql-server-intorduction-to-service-broker-and-sample-script/)**

Comment: @RGI: I did try similar starters and it worked. The problem is that I need to learn more and set it for the database that was not created by myself. The reason for the question is not that I do not understand the basics of the Service Broker. The reason is that I observed the error and I want to learn how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
alter authorization on database::[<your_SSB_DB>] to [sa];
```

The EXECUTE AS infrastructure requires `dbo` to map to a valid login. Service Broker uses the EXECUTE AS infrastructure to deliver the messages. A typical scenario that runs into this problem is a corporate laptop when working from home. You log in to the laptop using cached credentials, and you log in into the SQL using the same Windows cached credentials. You issue a `CREATE DATABASE` and the `dbo` gets mapped to your corporate domain account. However, the EXECUTE AS infrastructre *cannot* use the Windows cached accounts, it requires direct connectivity to the Active Directory. The maddening part is that things work fine the next day at office (your laptop is again in the corp network and can access to AD...). You go home in the evening, continue with Lesson 3... and all of the sudden it doesn't work anymore. Make the whole thing seem flimsy and unreliable. Is just the fact that AD conectivity is needed...

Another scenatio that leads to the same problem is caused by the fact that databases reteint the SID of their creator (the Windows login that issues the `CREATE DATABASE`) when restored or attached. If you used a local account `PC1\Fred` when you create the DB and then copy/attach the database to PC2, the account is invalid on PC2 (it is scoped to PC1, of course). Again, not much is affected but EXECUTE AS is, and this causes Service Broker to give the error you see.

And last example is when the DB is created by a user that later leaves the company and the AD account gets deleted. Seems like revenge from his part, but he's innocent. The production DB just stops working, simply because it's *his* SID that the `dbo` maps too. Fun...

By simply changing the `dbo` to `sa` login you fix this whole EXECUTE AS thing and all the moving parts that depend on it (and SSB is probably the biggest dependency) start working.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot. I do not understand the details yet, but it simply works. Arthur C. Clarke: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic." ... if one does not understand how it works. This way, you are a magician for me :)

Comment: What is `<your_SSB_DB>` supposed to be?  The Database Name?

Answer (score 5):

You would need to grant receive on your target queue to your login. And it should work!

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GRANT RECEIVE ON [dbo].[YourTargetQueue]
TO [Mycomp\Petr];
GO
```

And you also need to grant send for your user, permission on Target Service should be sufficient, but let's enable on both services for the future.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2 ;
GO

GRANT SEND ON SERVICE::[//AWDB/1DBSample/InitiatorService]
TO [Mycomp\Petr] ;
GO

GRANT SEND ON SERVICE::[//AWDB/1DBSample/TargetService]
TO [Mycomp\Petr] ;
GO
```

Comment: It failed with the message: "Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot find the object 'dbo.TargetQueue1DB', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." I believe I can see the queue correctly. It is there. How can I check/set the permitions? Please, give me some hints what should I describe, and I will edit the question accordingly. Thanks for the response.

Comment: ops, I've included incorrect code at first, I've edited it above and it should work now, sorry!

Comment: OK. The `GRANT...` query was executed successfully, but the earlier error cited in the question remains. I admit my knowledge on how the security things work in MS SQL server is rather fuzzy. My goal is to learn the basics of Service Broker. I have downloaded the AdventureWorks2008R2 Data File (http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/198008). Can you tell me how to install/attach it to the SQL server so that I would have the rights to follow the lessons mentioned in the question? Thanks ;)

Comment: here is an article that shows how to attach databases to sql server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx

Comment: I tried to attach the database both ways (via mouse clicking, and via the query). Please, see what I did in the edited question. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: you will also need to grant send permissions for your account to the services, see my edited answer above

Comment: The queries were executed successfully, but the exactly same problem remains. I tried the same also with SQL Server Management Console launched "as administrator". Another observation also is that it is related to the AdventureWorks2008R2 ready-to-be-used database. When the database is created by myself (in the next tutorial that works with two separate databases), everything works fine. Could not the answer be hidden in *...because the principal "dbo" does not exist, or this type of principal cannot be impersonated...*?