# SqlDependency not updating cache

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, caching, sqldependency

I'm on a project using .NET 4.5, MVC, EF 6

I had naively implemented a caching system using the HttpRuntime cache and needed to invalidate the data I cache on updates to that data; except I forgot to take into account that our production server is published to a load balanced set of two servers... :|

So on production, after the data was updated, the app would sometimes serve the right data, and sometimes the old data depending on which server the request was hitting. Bad news bears.

So I decided to define a dependency on the SQL table *AcademicTerms* which is where my data is coming from. But I did something wrong, and I'm not sure what.

SQL that I ran to set up the permissions after enabling the Service Broker

```sql
EXEC sp_addrole 'sql_dependency_role'

GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE to sql_dependency_role
GRANT CREATE QUEUE to sql_dependency_role
GRANT CREATE SERVICE to sql_dependency_role
GRANT REFERENCES on
  CONTRACT::[http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]
  to sql_dependency_role
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO sql_dependency_role
GRANT SELECT to sql_dependency_role
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO sql_dependency_role
GRANT RECEIVE ON QueryNotificationErrorsQueue TO sql_dependency_role

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'sql_dependency_role', 'MY_ASPNET_APP_USERNAME'
```

My implementation of inserting new data after fetching and thus setting up the SqlDependency (hopefully less naive!):

```cs
private void insertIntoCache(
  AcademicTermLockingInfo newItem,
  string itemKey,
  Guid termID) {

  var dbContextConnection = db.Database.Connection;

  var connectionString = dbContextConnection.ConnectionString;
  // important step otherwise it won't work
  SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

  CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy {
    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(6)
  };

  CacheItem item = new CacheItem(itemKey, newItem);

  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();
    // command which will be used to notify updates - probably want to parametrize this
    using (SqlCommand command = 
     new SqlCommand(
        String.Format("SELECT Name, LockDate FROM dbo.AcademicTerms WHERE ID = '{0}'",
          termID),
        connection)) {

        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        SqlChangeMonitor monitor = new SqlChangeMonitor(dependency);

        policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(monitor);
        MemoryCache.Default.Set(item, policy);

        // execute once otherwise dependency not registered
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

---

Things I've done:

- Created two new users in SQL Server, `net` and `sanba`
- Added every NT* login and the sa login to the `net` user, added `net` to the `sql_dependency_role`
- Ran `grant alter on schema::sql_dependency_role to net` and `grant alter on schema::dbo to net`
- Check that my local SQL Server's `Broker Enabled` option is `True` under `Service Broker`
- Tried the web cache and the Memory Cache interchangeably (probably wouldn't change anything)
- Tried making the sql command string have a fully qualified name `DevUMS.dbo.AcademicTerms` and `dbo.AcademicTerms`
- I queried the `sys.dm_qn_subscriptions` and saw I had one subscription, good!
- I queried `DevUMS.sys.transmission_queue` and found an excpetion!
  `An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target
  queue. Error: 15517, State: 1. Cannot execute as the database
  principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of
  principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.`
- I found [this SO post with the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383145/sql-server-2008-service-broker-tutorial-cannot-receive-the-message-exception)

Comment: I am testing using **DevUMS.dbo.AcademicTerms** instead of dbo.AcademicTerms; my laptop is super slow so I'll test it at the office tmrw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret sauce I was missing was `alter authorization on database::DevUMS to [sa];` which I found on [the linked SO post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11561633/2378943).

There are a number of other steps, like adding a Role to use the appropriate login, but honestly, I'm really unsure as to whether or not those are actually necessary.

I'm going to publish a little later on today, and then I'll try to do the minimal amount of steps and document that here. I found the documentation in the wild to be very scattered and poor, so I hope to have this answer be a definitive place to refer to in the future

Comment: In further discussions, the core of my problem (cross server cache invalidation) was better suited to be solved using Redis rather than Query Notifications. So I don't think I'll update my answer with the minimal amount of steps.